R: passing foreach loop number (i) to an object and then passing that object to a function
In R,
I'm attempting to run the following foreach loop in parallel using the doFuture package
For some reason the loop number (i) is not being passed to set the object "Current_File"
(I originally wrote this in a for loop)
The function calculate_p_value() requires current_file to be set.
        plan(multisession,workers=Usable.Cores)
        
        Output <- foreach(i = 1:10) %dofuture%{
                    
                    current_file <- paste0(Run_Folder,"Run",i,".csv",sep = "")
                    
                    tryCatch(Results <- {calculate_p_value()}, error = function(e){print(e)})

        }


The easiest way to parallelize things in R (that cover 99% of the usages) is with mclapply. Functional constructs like lapply are intrinsically parallelizable.
library(parallel)

mclapply(1:10, 
 function (i) 
  {
    current_file <- paste0("Run",i,".csv",sep = "")
    return(current_file);
  } )

It just runs the function in parallel for each elements of the 1:10 list, and return a list with the 10 results. Straightforward functional way to do things.

Thanks I forgot to mention I'm on Windows which doesn't support mclapply
